# R: caret (elasticnet): ridge regression: understanding the returned parameters

Tags: r, ridge-regression, caret

I wanted to play around with the ridge regression in caret (which apparently uses elasticnet), so I did two experiments:

- use the original data
- use the modified data where the values of `x2` are multiplied by `0.5`.

The value of `ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure` in the first case is

`x1       x2        x3
0 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.4803075
2 0.000000 3.245819 2.3878478
3 1.464703 2.543341 3.4790604`

Where does that come from? (The tested lambdas were only three: $0$, $10^{-4}$ and $10^{-1}$).

Apparently, the last line corresponds to the computed parameters (see `beta_true` values in the code below). It this always the case?

Moreover, if I compare the coefficients for the variable `x2` (the values `b1` and `b2`), it turns out that `b2 = 2 b1`. This seems to be wrong since the optimisation function of ridge regression should be
$$
\sum_{(x, y)} (y - \sum_i \beta_i x_i)^2 + \lambda ||\beta||_2^2\text{,}
$$
so making $\beta_2$ twice as big in the second case should keep the preditions $\hat{y} =\sum_i \beta_i x_i$ unchanged, but should increase the penalty term, so choosing a somewhat smaller $\beta_2$ should be preferred (the chosen lambda was not 0).

The same happens (`b2 = 2 b1`) when

- the number of examples is larger, e.g., 100 or 1000
- I specify the possible values of lambda in `tuneGrid` parameter, e.g., `tuneGrid = data.frame(lambda = 11.1)`

The code:

```
library(caret)

A = matrix(runif(30), ncol=3)
beta_true = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
Y = A %*% beta_true
Y = Y + runif(length(Y)) * 0.1

data = as.data.frame(A)
data$y = Y
colnames(data) = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y")

set.seed(123)
ridgeFit = train(y ~ ., data=data, method="ridge")
print(ridgeFit)
print(ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure)
b1 = ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure[4,2]

data$x2 = 0.5 * data$x2
set.seed(123)
ridgeFit = train(y ~ ., data=data, method="ridge")
print(ridgeFit)
print(ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure)
b2 = ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure[4,2]
print(sprintf("b2 - 2 b1 = %f", b2 - 2 * b1))
```

---

EDIT:

Using glmnet's method glment directly seems to reflect the changes in the data correctly. However, that does not solve the original question.

Comment: glmnet normalises the input by default.  have you checked the same is not done with caret?

Comment: @seanv507 The same IS done with caret: additional arguments can be passed to the train method; I tried and passed `standardize = FALSE` to the train calls above and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `method="ridge"`, the model is fitted using elastic net, you can check it [enter link description here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html). To answer your questions:

i) beta.pure, the first line of all zeros is for the null model, only intercept.

ii) you need to check again what is the lambda in the 2nd model. Caret selects the model with the least deviance and puts it as the finalModel. If i reran your example, I get a chosen lambda of 0 or 1e-04 which is really small. If you increase the lambda you will see that your beta2 with the scaled down data gets penalized more. And in your example, you need to have a huge lambda before you see it shrinking..

So we can check this:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(111)
A = matrix(runif(30), ncol=3)
beta_true = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
Y = A %*% beta_true
Y = Y + runif(length(Y)) * 0.1

data = as.data.frame(A)
data$y = Y
colnames(data) = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y")
data2 = data
data2$x2 = 0.5 * data2$x2
```

To check these models, a good practice might be to write a function to keep track of these:

```
fit = function(dat){
ridgeFit = train(y ~ ., data=dat, method="ridge")
beta = ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure
data.frame(
b2 = beta[nrow(beta),2],
lambda = ridgeFit$finalModel$lambda
)
}

sapply(list(data=data,data2=data2),function(i)fit(i))

       data     data2   
b2     2.537871 5.076027
lambda 1e-04    0
```

We can use run the ridge regression from enet, which will show you the effect of lambda, basically only at 100 does it start going down:

```
library(elasticnet)
fit_enet = function(dat,lam){
    beta = enet(x=as.matrix(dat[,1:3]),y=dat[,4],lambda=lam)$beta.pure
    data.frame(b2 = beta[nrow(beta),2],lambda = lam)
    }    

sapply(c(0.01,0.1,1,10,100),function(i){
fit_enet(data2,i)
})

       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]     [,5]    
b2     5.048046 4.834376 4.05609 3.596255 3.532956
lambda 0.01     0.1      1       10       100
```

Comment: I am so sorry, but the question is not "Which $\lambda$ is the optimal one" but rather  i) what is inside `ridgeFit$finalModel$beta.pure`, and ii) why `b2 = 2 b1` (independently of $\lambda$).

Comment: beta are the coefficients.. beta.pure, the first row is for a model with only intercept, it is used in calculating the null deviance

Comment: Ok, so every next row adds one additional term to the model, I suppose. i) DONE (Thanks!) ii) remains open

Comment: i don't see the b2 = 2 b1 in your example, basically, your assumptions only hold when the coefficients are penalized according to the lambda

Comment: however if you use caret or cv.glmnet, it automatically goes to the lower lambda values, which minimize deviance, and throws you the coefficients which are close to what you simulated

Comment: When I run the code (`b1` and `b2` are defined in the lines 16 and 23), the final output is `"b2 - 2 b1 = 0.000000"`.  If the chosen $\lambda > 0$, this should not be the case.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for clarifying. I edit my answer now.